# What happens with account ownership and multiple migrations?

Tags: discussion, migration, user-accounts

Let us posit three sites, A, B, and C. A given user has an account on sites A and B, but not C. If that user posts a question on site A which is then migrated to site C, the ownership of the question will be lost. If that question is then migrated again to site B, will the user reclaim it?

Specifically, if a question was asked on Stack Overflow, migrated to Meta Stack Overflow (at the time a separate site), and now migrated to the new Meta Stack Overflow (now a per-site meta of SO, with linked main/meta accounts), would the Stack Overflow user reclaim the question on the new Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: Gah, I know I've seen a discussion like this before and that the answer was "that will work just fine", but I can't freaking find it.

Comment: Double migrations are  a bad idea and tend to break stuff. For that reason they are not possible anymore as far as I know.

Comment: Multi-migrations are **extremely** rare, in any case and may not even be allowed anymore. But I *think* a migrated post has a reference to the *network profile* of the OP, so when the user registers at site C it *should* Just Work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the ownership carries over - they'll appear as a sort of 'grayed out' version of themselves on the site where they don't have a profile. As soon as they create a profile, any posts that they own will be transferred to them as owners.

This *occasionally* breaks, though not nearly as often as it used to, but we can manually tell the system to go dig and look for unmapped posts belonging to a user and map them correctly. We *really* like to avoid multi-migrations, but we can't always do that.

On our end there's some post meta-data that allows us to ascertain the owner of any given post in the database, unless that's been scrubbed due to the user being removed because they're under 13 years of age. That's tied to the account level, the thing that links all of your profiles together, so it works on all of the sites.